# Move image inside image-element

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have an image-element, in which images are shown. How can I move images inside that element, without moving the element itself? I want to achieve a moving-image effect.

This is my XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="tnail" Margin="0,0,0,90" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/Img/Apl4.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to move the image, try applying a RenderTransform:

```
<Image x:Name="tnail" Margin="0,0,0,90"
       Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/Img/Apl4.jpg">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform OffsetX="10"/>
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

You can also access this in code-behind to set the offset

```
var trans = tnail.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
trans.OffsetX = 20;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `trans.Offset` isn't showing up, that setter is not available and `<TranslateTransform OffsetX="10"/>` is also not working in XAML.